# Como acessar o metodo showCallScreenWithDialpad?

Tags: java, android

Não estou conseguindo acessar o método `showCallScreenWithDialpad` da classe `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony.AIDL`. Já tentei por `reflection` e não consegui. Não tem como instanciar a classe `ITelephony$Stub`. Também tentei por `bindService` e também não consegui (o `bindService` retorna `false`). Alguém pode ajudar?

O que eu quero fazer é ocultar a tela de chamada do Android, ou seja, fazer uma chamada telefônica e não aparecer a tela padrão de chamada.

Abaixo segue o que eu tentei.

Por reflection:

```
 .
 .
 .
 classCallManager = classLoader.loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub");
 getITelephonyMethod = classCallManager.getMethod("onTransact", cArg); 
 objeto = classCallManager.newInstance();
 getITelephonyMethod.invoke(objeto, 1, "1234567", "1234567", 1);
```

Isso dá um erro:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null receiver

Porque a variável objeto é igual a `null`, porque a classe não pode ser instanciada:

> W/System.err: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub cannot be instantiated

Agora por bindService:

```
    .
    . 
    .

    final ServiceConnection conexao = this;
    Class classeServico2 = ITelephony.class;

    boolean resultado = bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, classeServico2), conexao, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

E o `bindService` retorna `false`.

Comment: Você pode mostrar o código que você já tentou? Que erro você teve?

Comment: O que seu código faz exatamente?! Tem como você dar mais algum detalhe?!

Comment: O que eu quero fazer é ocultar a tela de chamada do android, ou seja, fazer uma chamada telefonica e nao aparecer a tela padrao de chamada.

Comment: [`ITelephony$Stub` é uma classe abstrata.](https://github.com/danghvu/WeChatRE/blob/master/src/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony$Stub.java) Logo, não pode ser instanciada diretamente. Apenas por meio de subclasses.

Comment: E tem a possibilidade de acessar a funçao q eu quero?